# Detect URL change in WPF WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, url, webbrowser-control

Using the WebBrowser in WPF, how can I check for a change in the URL? is there an even that can be fired when it hits a condition? Below I have a button event that sets the `App.browserLinkCheck` as the target URL, and opens the WebBrowser instance.

```
private void btNextWelcomeNewHire_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.borwserLinkCheck = App._PasswordSyncWebLink;
    webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(App.borwserLinkCheck));
    //webBrowser.Navigating += webBrowser_Navigating;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event to detect or even cancel navigation in the webBrowser.

You can save the current `WebBrowser` url and compare it with the new one received in the `Navigating` event and compare them to see if it has changed.

```
    private Uri currentUri;

    void myBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentUri.AbsolutePath != e.Uri.AbsolutePath)
        {
            // Url has changed ...

            // Update current uri
            currentUri = e.Uri;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick respond. When I run the build, I get 
<br></br>
this error "NullReferenceException was unhandled by the user"
App.borwserLinkCheck = App._PasswordSyncWebLink;

webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(App.borwserLinkCheck));

I'm calling the webBrowser within the button event, then the page loads and I get the error.

Comment: @MarcinLimanski Update your question with your code so it would be simplier to detect where your problem is

Comment: any suggestions on the `NullReferenceException was unhandled by the user`?

Comment: @MarcinLimanski Have you tried debugging it? At what point is the `NullReferenceException` raised? is assume it's being raised regardless to `Navigating` event since it's comment out...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Omribitan example I have managed to over come the NullException issue by adjusting the code:

```
private String targetStringToCompare = "www.example.com";

void myBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString() == targetStringToCompare)
    {
        // Do something when the change will be detected
    }
}
```

Comment: The comparison should still probably use `!=` as in the original answer. Otherwise you aren't actually detecting that the `Uri` changed, but rather checking that it stayed the same.